# How to replace Google animation?

Tags: android, android-source, boot-animation

How to Replace Google Animation Displayed on Boot in Compiling AOSP 13 Version，thanks.

[Google logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcAbe.jpg)

I'd like to change it to another picture.

But I can't find the place, I just replaced the bootanimation.zip displayed behind google and put it in the system/media/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo is a static png. When the phone is booting, the static logo will be shown until the android boot animation be played. It's shown by low level system not Android. You can not change it by modifing the Android source.

It should be [flashed](https://romprovider.com/chnage-logo-splash-android/) to a dedicated partition.

Comment: I thought it was displayed after kernel and before bootanimation. Thanks. 
Is there a way to turn off this logo?